# Configuring Geth node started by Mist

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

When I launch mist, it starts up a geth node by default. How do I specify the configurations for this node?

Specifically, I just want to achieve the equivalent of `geth --cache=1024` which I can do via a CLI prior to launching the mist GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mist now accepts new options that can be passed to the underlying node, which by default is `geth`.  You can use all the same options from the node, you just need to prefix them with `--node`.  For instance, the `geth` option `--datadir` becomes `mist` option `--node-datadir`.

My mist launcher looks something like this:

```
mist --node-cache 512 --node-maxpeers 50 --node-port 30304
```

On linux, you can see your options were used to launch geth with a command like the following:

```
ps aux | grep geth
```

Answer (score 2):

You can start Geth with desired parameters, and then run Mist. In that case, Mist will not start a new Geth instance, but use the existing one instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's what I've been doing so far, but was hoping for a mist specific UI setting that'll make it easier. I reached out Fabian on twitter (https://twitter.com/olshansky/status/868289837564121089) but am still waiting to hear back.